# Making a deck using RXJS - Redux Observable

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

well I want to make a poker Evaluator using React-Redux-Redux Observable. I've already made it with react - redux and now I want to Add some Epics which will overwrite all my buisness logic. Until now I made my deck with plain Javascript. For an example.

```
  createDeck() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.suits.length; i++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < this.ranks.length; x++) {
        var card = {
          rank: this.ranks[x].rank,
          weight: this.ranks[x].weight,
          suit: this.suits[i]
        };
        this.deck.push(card);
      }
    }
    this.shuffleDeck();
  }
```

But now i want to convert this to RxJs code, but I am getting stuck. Because Redux Observables need to get an action and then give an action (actions in - actions out) , I am a little bit confused how I would implement this. Have you guys any ideas? I am really stuck to this model...

Comment: The code example you provide wouldn't really benefit from a rewrite to RxJS. Can you give examples of some other code, maybe some that involves handling events like player bets or dealer actions?

Comment: Also a general tip - epics are functions that take a stream of actions and return a stream of actions. That doesn't mean they need to use the provided action stream to create a new one. For example, this is a valid epic: `() => interval(1000).pipe(mapTo({ type: 'TICK' }))`